# Google Analytics 4 isn't working wirh custom Wordpress' theme's pages

Tags: wordpress

I made a custom non-editable Wordpress theme with custom pages and posts. I followed the directions Google gives to put Analytics 4 into the last line before the head closing tag. It does recognize when a user is in the page in realtime but always logs it as if the user stayed in the homepage. Regardless of whichever page the user is on, the analytics for page title and screen name only logs the homepage and never changes. I've tried with switching around the position of the code and some plugins too, it doesn't change anything. What am i failing to check or what alternatives do i have?

The script is added to the header, and the header is added dynamically with get_header(); on all the pages templates. Could it be a conflict with how the custom pages are created? The functions are managed by a snippets plugin and created with a generator.

Here's the repository if u need it

https://github.com/DairaF/wp-identidades/

Comment: Are you only loading this script on the homepage template? You need to make sure the script is loaded on every page. Usually best to add to header.php.

Comment: Yes! The script is added to the header, and the header is added dynamically with get_header(); on all the pages templates